# I can't access my Aol.com mail account

Tags: account-management, aol-mail

I use my AOL mail account as a backup for my Gmail account. My Gmail account forwards all mail to AOL Mail. Every once in a while I delete some of my AOL mail to make room for more, as I changed my password, I couldn't get back in. I don't pass the secret Q&A test so I'm stuck out.

I have no access to AOL support without being logged in, and yet I signed up a different account telling them about my problem, they never respond!

The mailbox is full and mail is bouncing to my Gmail.

Should I abandon my backup or is there a solution?